# How to change info in a histogram in r?

Tags: r, histogram

I'm trying to build a histogram in which the X-axis shows each case I'm working with (my matrix's info includes the murders' resolution rate for different police stations in one city for a year), each police station, and the Y-axis would show the resolution rate (from 0 to 1). So, there would be 51 bars, one for each police station, and each one should reach one of those rates from 0 to 1.
But when I run hist with my matrix, the X-axis displays resolution rates and the Y-axis displays the frequency, the number of police stations that reach each resolution rate. 
How can I get the result I wrote before? This is the code I'm using:

```
anobase<-matrix(CResolucion[seleccion_ano==2018], length(seleccion_estado), 1)

rownames(anobase) <- seleccion_estado

colnames(anobase) <- 2018

hist(anobase)
```

(and, yeah, I'm new at using R)

[image]

So, that's the plot. As you see, the X-axis displays values from 0 to 1. These values represent the resolution rate said before (result from dividing solved murders by the total of murders registered). The Y-axis on the other hand displays a frequency from 0-15. Then, each bar shows how many cases have each resolution rate. What I want to do is show in the X-axis each police station, so each bar would be a police station, and they should reach that resolution rate from 0-1 (Y-axis). I hope I'm being clear.

Comment: It is hard to answer this question at this moment because I do not understand what the problem is. If you can edit your question with your plot and what you want to change, that would help.

Comment: I editted it, hope it's clearer now!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want a histogram; you want a column or bar chart. Histograms summarize the distribution of a single continuous variable; column charts compare values of a continuous variable across categories (here, police stations).

You haven't posted a reproducible example, so I can't tell exactly what's going on with your data. Let's assume, though, that you have a vector of resolution rates called `rates` and a vector of station names associated with those rates called `stations`. In base R, you could then create a column chart with `barplot(rates, names.arg = stations)`.